# 30-pin Dock Connector and 3.5mm jack

Tags: audio, hardware, lightning

Here's what I got, a Panasonic docking system without aux in. I want to use an AirPort Express and turn it into a AirPlay-enabled speaker, so I need a cable that has a female 30-pin connector at one end, and 3.5mm jack at another.

I did do some research on the Internet, I see people selling those, BUT, since I live in Taiwan, I can't get one. I'm wondering if I can buy two cables:

- a [30-pin connector extender cable](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=30%20pin%20cable%20specification&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#q=30%20pin%20extender%20cable&hl=en&safe=off&client=safari&sa=X&tbo=u&rls=en&source=univ&tbm=shop) that has a female 30 pin connector at one end that I'll need to attach to the male dock 30 pin connector
- a male to male headphone cable

If I knew the pin out for the 30 pin protocol, I might be able to cut and splice the two together.

What I'm needing to try this experiment is to know what the pin out is for a 30 pin connector and if I can simply wire the audio out from the AirPort Express into a female 30 pin connector by simply splicing wires. (or to hear from someone that knows that I would need to have some other resistor or voltage present to tell the dock that it's getting an stereo input from "my iPhone" which is really the cable to the express.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @patrix I'm trying to make that system AirPlay-enabled.

Comment: This set-up would not make it an AirPlay enabled device. There's a big difference to the data streamed over AirPlay and the data sent over the 30pin cable, so there would be a lot more engineering envolved than a simple adapter, and I doubt anything like this is available if at all possible.

Comment: Hopefully my edit helps clarify what I think the OP is asking. Best of luck shane in your hacking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm trying the very same thing. I made one myself but the dock station didn't see anything connected so didn't enable the audio signals. I then saw a cable 30pin to 3.5 on the Internet which I ordered and this is doing exactly the same thing. The dock station only uses pin 1 or 2 for signal Gnd and pins 3 and 4 for left and right audio signal.

Comment: Is the cable is dock extender separable, so I can see each pin?

Comment: @ShaneHsu You won't need to see each pin in the female connector - instead you'll just need to know which cables are which - so a multimeter with small leads will show you which pin is connected to which wire once you have a [good wiring diagram](http://pinouts.ru/PortableDevices/ipod_pinout.shtml).